# How to mimic rename file operations on a backup disk having same layout?

Tags: rsync, backup, pcmanfm

I want to tidy my external harddrive. This harddrive is kept in sync with a backup via rsync.
When I move/rename (and delete for convinience) files on the disk, it would be nice if those fast actions could also be performed on the backup drive analogical, so I don't have to rsync the corresponding files again.

For tidying I like to use a GUI (i.e. pcmanfm).
Are there any tools capable of this?

//Edited b/c delete makes my point harder to see - I want to avoid rsync deleting renamed/moved files and copying them again to the new location. And I'd like to stick to the tidying process as I'm used to (move/rename and delete things in a file manager with graphical interface).

Comment: With rsync you can spesify the `--delete` parameter to make rsync delete files no longer present in your source directory.

Comment: @Sven Yes - I was not clever mentioning delete in Q. Rename/move a file is the main case I am looking for. Rename on my external drive, is quite fast - as it would be on the backup disk. If I move a file and rsync deletes it and copies it from source again - it takes time. In case of big files quite a lot.